# Rails - Include a Date/Time Stamp in a string on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my def create controller I'd like to include something along the lines of:

:description = > 'Uploaded on May 27, 2010"

How can I make the May 27, 2010 dynamic in the controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
:description => "Uploaded on #{Date.today.strftime("%b %d,%Y")}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you say you want to make `May 27, 2010` then you mean you want to set the current date. For that you need to use:

```
:description = > "Uploaded on " + Time.now.to_s
```

Output will be:

```
"Uploaded on Fri Oct 22 21:48:49 -0700 2010"
```

There are [many options](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html) in the Time class which you can use. This is an interesting read for [timezone consideration](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/1/25/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-easier-timezones) for Rails.

Comment: well I'd like it to be contained in a string... "Uploaded on XXXXX"